# Problem with LightDM & KDM

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, display-manager, plasma, kdm

I'm a Kubuntu 12.10 x86_64 user.
I recently found an exquisite KDM theme on (name of KDE artwork site).
However, as the default display manager in Kubuntu is LightDM, I installed KDM with:

```
sudo apt-get install kdm
```

Then, I did

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and chose KDM.
After I rebooted, the Plymouth splash (the Kubuntu Ubuntu-circle-of-friends-surrounded-by-cogs) was stuck in a loop, therefore I Alt-F2'ed and after logging in, typed in:

```
sudo startx
```

This worked the first time, and the System Settings app was expanded by the new sub-app "Login Screen" next to "Login Screen(LightDM)", but after a reboot, it did not work at all (it said something about a timeout in X-authority or some other such thing). 
So I chose LightDM again in the text shell and rebooted. Once again it looped, but this time I was able to log into the desktop (as root).
I searched for this and all I got was generic "I boot to busybox shell" and "GUI fails" questions.

Answer (score 1):

ok after switching on your PC at login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> Then login there , after that type this command with out any mistakes and then restart .

```
ln -s -f "$XAUTHORITY" ~/.Xauthority
```

hope that helps .

Comment: Will keep that in mind (aka on a piece of paper) when I do something like that in the future. However, my dumb self did not realize that:

a) one has to set a KDM theme
b) and the KDM config app must be run as root to do that.


Works alright with the Kharma for Kubuntu theme and splash.
Thanks anyway and sorry for wasting your time.